# Kinvey Android SDK - File Uploading - SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: android, file, upload, socket-timeout-exception, kinvey

I'm trying to upload a file from my android device to the Kinvey File Storage, but I get:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.
```

I do see the file uploaded on the Kinvey Console, but it's corrupted and the file size when I try to download is 10mb, where as the original file size is ~50mb. The code is as follows (pretty close to the documentation):

```java
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "images.zip");

FileMetaData metadata = new FileMetaData();  //create the FileMetaData object
metadata.setId("images");
metadata.setFileName("images.zip");
AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
acl.setGloballyReadable(true);
metadata.setAcl(acl);

mKinveyClient.file().upload(metadata, file, new UploaderProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
    }
});
```

I have posted the same question [here](http://support.kinvey.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200518593-File-Uploading-SocketTimeoutException-Read-timed-out) (Kinvey Support Forums).

**Update**

Following ewilly's answer I did some tests.

- Uploaded a file ~9mb. Works fine. Can download and extract file is not corrupted. Correct file size is displayed.
- Uploaded a file ~19mb, uploads without socketTimeoutException. **But** The uploaded file is corrupt. When downloading shows the file size as 10mb.
- Previous case still stands for file size ~ 50mb.

Answer (score 0):

I read the FAQ of the `kinvey` website. This may helps you:

I think youre file is too large. the `kinvey` API only allow files under 20MB to be imported, In your case, you can split the file into chunks or create a script to import using the REST API.

Comment: I have seen this, but I assumed this applied only when uploading files directly from the Kinvey Admin console on the web. Nevertheless I did some tests, see updated question.

Comment: From your test results, it seems that over 10MB you begin to have problem (wrong display dimmension) and for realy big file Timeout exception.

Comment: Yes that is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

have you attempted to retry the file upload after a failure is caught?

note that 50mb is a rather large file, so you might also want to ensure the device is on wifi.  If you are using a data plan, and the connection cuts out unfortunately there isn't much that can be done about it.

Comment: For upload. It's on a physical device (HTC One). I have tested both on local WiFi network and my LTE connection. Both are very reliable.

I'm testing the file download from the Kinvey Web Console on the browser. It's a zip file by the way and, and it's corrupted when downloaded, and the file size is 10mb.

I have tested this problem further now, and noticed that files under 10mb work fine. But files over 10mb have a problem. 10mb is pretty arbitrary, it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation that there is a limit like this.

Any support from Kinvey?